# How to stay on same page after clicking on ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I am new to ASP.NET MVC.I am making my Web App and want to implement adding friends from list, and after clicking on link "Dodaj" (English: "Add") I want to save my friend, but to stay on same page, and just to update my list.[image]

In my Profil.cshtml I have:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.neprijatelji)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IME_GOSTA)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PREZIME_GOSTA)
        </td>

        <td>

            @Html.ActionLink("Dodaj", "Dodaj", new { id = item.EMAIL_GOSTA })

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

In My ProfilController.cs Action Dodaj I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Dodaj( string id)
{
    string posiljalac = Session["idGosta"].ToString();
    PRIJATELJI pr = new PRIJATELJI();
    pr.EMAIL_GOSTA = posiljalac;
    pr.EMAIL_GOSTA1 = id;
    pr.PRIJATELJI_OD = System.DateTime.Now;
    db.PRIJATELJIs.Add(pr);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Profil"); //O just want to do some change and stay on same page
}
```

What I get as result is Error 404 not found. I know this is wrong, but How I should implement this?

**UPDATE:**
Here is what did I try:
In my Profil.cshtml I have done:
Here is What I did try: In Profil.cshtml I have this:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.neprijatelji)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IME_GOSTA)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PREZIME_GOSTA)
        </td>

        <td>
            <a href="#" onclick="AddFriend(this)" data-id='@item.EMAIL_GOSTA' > Dodaj </a>

            <script>
                function AddFriend(ele)
                {
                    var values={id:$(ele).attr('data-id')};
                    $.post("/Profil/Dodaj", values, function (abc) {
                        var result=$.parseJSON(abc)
                        if (result.isAdded == "success") { alert("I just added this alert that my if isn't empty"); }
                            //Logic to append tr to existing table
                        else { alert("Some alert"); }
                        //raise exception or alert maybe.

                    });
                } 
                </script>
                </td>
```

In my ProfilController I have this:

```
    public JsonResult Dodaj(string id)
    {
        string posiljalac = Session["idGosta"].ToString();
        PRIJATELJI pr = new PRIJATELJI();
        pr.EMAIL_GOSTA = posiljalac;
        pr.EMAIL_GOSTA1 = id;
        pr.PRIJATELJI_OD = System.DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            db.PRIJATELJIs.Add(pr);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { isAdded = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { isAdded = "failure" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

When I put breakpoint on JavaScript function I get:
the breakpoint will not be hit no executable code is associated with this line

When I click on "Dodaj" it seems that it only recognizes href="#" because from the link: http://localhost:50884/Profil/Profil then I get http://localhost:50884/Profil/Profil#

Also, do I have to do some additional settings to make my JavaScript code works. Should I save my JS code in different file then Profil.cshtml?

Comment: is the `Profil` Action in the same Controller as the `Dodaj` Action?  If not, then you have to explicitly give the Controller name in which `Profil` resides.  Otherwise, you will continue to receive 404 errors

Comment: In reference to staying on the same page when trying to add someone to a list, you may want to look into [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: "Dodaj" is in same Controller as the "Profil" Action.

Answer (score 2):

Here instead of using an action Link try to use an ajax post.And return JSON result from an action  Dodaj. Then if the returned result is the success then append a new tr to a table through Jquery otherwise return an error.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.neprijatelji)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IME_GOSTA)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PREZIME_GOSTA)
    </td>

    <td>
    <a href="#" onclick="AddFriend(this)"  data-id='@item.EMAIL_GOSTA'/>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

JS Code

```
<script>
function AddFriend(ele)
{
   var values={id:$(ele).attr('data-id')};
   $.post(someRootPath + "/Profil/Dodaj", values, function (abc) {
   var result=$.parseJSON(abc)
   if(result.isAdded=="success")
     //Logic to append tr to existing table
   else
     //raise exception or alert maybe.

    });
}
```

And Controller

```
    public JsonResult Dodaj( string id)
    {
        string posiljalac = Session["idGosta"].ToString();
        PRIJATELJI pr = new PRIJATELJI();
        pr.EMAIL_GOSTA = posiljalac;
        pr.EMAIL_GOSTA1 = id;
        pr.PRIJATELJI_OD = System.DateTime.Now;
        try{
        db.PRIJATELJIs.Add(pr);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { isAdded = "success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { isAdded = "failure" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Although I havnt tested the code but approch should be like this .

Comment: I did everything as you did. In my Profil.cshtml this JavaScript function is never being called. :(

Comment: whats the issue? did you see the browser console, are there any javascript errors in there. can you please post the code so that we can debug and resolve an issue.

Comment: Here is What I did:

Comment: Please have a separation between your  razor code and javascript code.It can also be written inside same cshtml file. The code actually hits a javascript code even if it is appending # to url you also remove href to avoid this.The possible issue may be the function is getting called but there may be issue with JQUery as you see $.post is not a plain javascipt function.So please add Jquery js in your layout to provide support to these functions.